# Silently print in the web page

Tags: java, asp.net, apache-flex, visual-c++, printing

All, I am trying to look for some solution to print the data in the webpage `silently`,
the printer type is `Datamax e-4205A Label Printer`, But so far I am stuck with it , Any Idea?
Any way , Is it possible to program an Activex control based on the printer API? thanks.

Comment: *"All, I am trying to look for some solution to print the data in the webpage silently"*  That's a *great* way to dump 12000 pages of coupons for Viagra to the company printer.  :)

Comment: +1 :)))) `silently` means no dialog, no setting, just directly send the data  to printer.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The actually problem is I just don't know if Activex Control is the best solution to solve it . Hope you can give me some suggestion or direction. thanks.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am interested with the problem you mention , How can you prevent this (dump 12000 pages of coupons) ? thanks.